# Dealing with Answers that should be comments

Tags: discussion

I realise it's a deficiency in the SE system, but a new user (from memory) can't post comments to questions or answers, unless it's their own.

A lot of users throughout SE as a whole do this, post an answer that really should be a comment on a question or the answer in question because they can't offer said comment because their rep os too low.

How should this be handled?

For example, in this question:

[error: redefinition of ' '](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/error-redefinition-of/26833#26833)

There is a down-voted answer which someone else has come out in support of (rightly or wrongly) but can't add a comment because their rep is 1. But in the scheme of things, if this is in fact valid, then it could serve as a valuable comment and aid to future searchers.

For the interim I am going to manually create the comment for him and recommend his answer for deletion, but I'm open to suggestion on what the "norm" is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Flag it and let a moderator take a peek.** We have the tools to directly convert an answer to a comment (so that it looks like it was posted by the user who posted the answer) or delete the post altogether. We also have the know-how to properly respond to the user to educate them about Stack Exchange and its practices.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!